# std::basic_ifstream throws std::bad_cast

Tags: c++, file-io, c++11, io, ifstream

I am trying to read data from a file using below code. (Note that you need to enable C++11 features on GCC to make this compile.)

```
#include <fstream>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "test.cpp";
    std::basic_ifstream<byte> in(filename, std::basic_ifstream<byte>::in | std::basic_ifstream<byte>::binary);
    in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    byte buf[5];
    in.read(buf, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when reading data I get an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
```

This happens when the `in.read(buf, 5)` command is invoked.

I know that I can suppress this exception by not setting the exception mask I set but this does not fix the problem, it only masks it. Without an exception mask, the code keeps working but 0 characters are read.

Does anyone know why this exception is thrown? And how do I make it go away?

Comment: For me, it doesn't even compile: `no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::basic_ifstream<byte>`

Comment: @H2CO3 As stated in the introduction, you need to enable C++11. Otherwise the constructor for the `basic_ifstream` does not exist. Alternative fix: use `filename.c_str()` instead of `filename`.

Comment: This problem has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19205531/331024 It has a full implementation of char_traits<uint8_t> and codecvt<uint8_t,char,...>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c++ STL only contains two specializations of char_traits:

```
   struct char_traits < char >;
   struct char_traits <wchar_t >;
```

For the code posted to work a definition of `char_traits<byte>` is required.

More details in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604431/c-reading-unsigned-char-from-file-stream)

Answer (score 3):

If you redefine `byte` as `char` the `bad_cast` exception will no longer
occur.

I presume the `basic_ifstream` template is not fully debugged for
`unsigned char` specialization. According to the Standard § 27.3,
`char_traits<CharType>` need only be instantiated by the library
for `CharType` = `{char|char16_t|char32_t|wchar_t}`