# C++, ifstream, and char

Tags: c++, gcc, char, ifstream, signedness

I'm reading *PNG* files from disk and inserting the bytes into a vector of chars, instantiated with the `new` keyword.

Opening the file:

```
std::ifstream file("./images/orange.png", std::ios_base::binary);
```

Instantiating a vector of length 8 (`#define PNG_SIGNATURE 8`), where all elements are initially an empty char:

```
std::vector<char>* header_buff { new std::vector<char>(PNG_SIGNATURE, ' ') };
```

Writing bytes to the vector, where `f` is a reference to the file, and `b` is a pointer to my vector buffer:

```
std::vector<char> chunk_reader(std::vector<char>* b, std::ifstream &f) {
    char c { };

    for(int i { }; i < (*b).size(); ++i) {
        f.get(c);
        (*b)[i] = c;
    };

    return *b;
};
```

The first byte of a PNG is always going to be HEX `0x89`.

According to the reference material, the `std::ifstream` member type is of type `char`.

---

My question is, on my implementation: **MinGW GCC for Windows**, I'm able to debug my program and see the first byte of the PNG as a `signed char`, decimal value `-119`. I think for ease of parsing a stream of binary, I'd want to use `unsigned char`, so if I were to `seek` to a particular byte of interest, I could check if its unsigned value is correct in the source code as `137` instead of its signed representation.

To my knowledge, and based on the posts I've read on here with similar questions, C++ leaves the *signedness* of a `char` to the implementation for flexibility. So, if I insert the gcc flag `-funsigned-char`, I get the behavior I expect, and can visually see in the debugger the decimal value `137` for the first byte.

I've read on here from more experienced programmers that this is a band-aid, and to keep something like this to the source code for readability, aka a `reinterpreted cast` from `char` to `unsigned char`, which to my knowledge makes sense since they're both one byte of information.

But, then I see posts saying `reinterpret cast` is hacky, and should be left alone to the use cases it was designed for in the standard library.

Can someone offer some advice as to what is the best practice in this situation?

I'd ultimately like to perform certain validations of individual bytes, like in the case of a PNG the first byte of a named chunk will have a special meaning if it's an uppercase or lowercase ASCII character - which is simple if I'm dealing with unsigned chars and can use decimal values in the source code, in a `switch` statement for example.

I'm very new to C++, so I'd appreciate your advice. I'm interested in the best practices and scalability of designing such a system.

Comment: You probably don't need new to make your vector

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` operated on pointers, it is not clear how it would be used here.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've missed it, but why can't you use `unsigned char`? If it's too long, create an alias, eg [`using byte = unsigned char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). Or use [`std::uint8_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). And, of course there is also [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).

Comment: OT, but `#define PNG_SIGNATURE 8` should really be `constexpr auto PNG_SIGNATURE = 8`.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade OP asks about correct ('best practice') way to do the conversion. Whether they should read it as `char` and `reinterpret_cast` to `unsigned char`, use `-funsigned-char` or something else.

Comment: Your implementation takes a reference to a vector, modifies it, then returns a _copy_ if it. So you end up with two vectors.  Is that intended.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade the ifstream member type is of char, if I instantiate a vector of unsigned char, the compiler in my implementation will still use a signed char per what I can observe.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen oh I see, thanks for clarifying. In that case I'd say the best practice is not to use char in the first place :)

Comment: @Clifford Yes, this is just demonstrative. The `header_buffer` is deleted after the function call, I'm more asking about best practices regarding file streams and how systems interpret the char type, I wrote this as an example not as a final product.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Do you know of a better way to read file streams other than `ifstream`? I believe all filestreams in cpp are of some type of char.

Comment: Not sure I follow your justification, but note that it is likely to lead to much less efficient code.

Comment: @h4yf oh I get what you are asking now. Sorry, I got lost in all other details. For generic solution, see Clifford's answer. If you only care about windows, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500336/4358570

Answer (score 1):

I know you are trying to avoid `reinterpret_cast`, but this is what I would do. Main advantage of this method is that you are not reading the data one byte at a time.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

constexpr auto PNG_SIGNATURE = 8;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fs{"/path/to/file", std::ios::binary};

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> buf(PNG_SIGNATURE);
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size());

    // use buf

    return 0;
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/vTne7Gj64

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, what would probably be nice here would be for the `ifstream` to read a stream of `std::byte`s, in which case your entire question kind of evaporates, because you could just read the correct number of `std::byte`s, and have what you want.

Unfortunately, iostreams predate the addition of `std::byte` by a few decades. Worse, they're based closely on C's I/O model, which worked primarily with `char`s since time immemorial (though with C I/O, you typically start by reading data into an `int`, then check for `EOF`, and only convert the result to `char` after determining that what you just read is not EOF).

As for how to deal with your specific situation. A PNG header is rather different from most things we read from files. In particular, a PNG header doesn't really contain any information of interest--it's just an 8-byte signature that gives a pretty strong indication that what comes after it is actually PNG data.

As such, I'd personally go about this *almost* entirely differently than you have. Situations like this (where we expect some specific data in an input file, and just need to verify that it's present) arise fairly frequently, and I find that it's useful to overload `operator>>` to make it relatively easy:

```cpp
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, unsigned char const *expected) {
    while (*expected && (*expected == is.peek()))
        is.ignore(1);
    if (*expected) {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Putting that to use in your case (reading/verifying a PNG header) would look something like this:

```cpp
unsigned char const *pngHeader = "\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A";

std::ifstream input("somefile.png");

if (!input >> pngHeader) {
    std::cerr << "somefile.png is not really a PNG File\n");
}
```

Looking at your question more generally, however, let's consider reading a subsequent chunk from a PNG file. A chunk format looks roughly like this:

```cpp
struct PngChunk {
    std::uint32_t type;

    // length is stored implicit in data.length()
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> data;
    std::uint32_t CRC;
};
```

To read this, I would use a `reinterpret_cast`, something on this order:

```cpp
std::istream &operator(std::istream &is, PngChunk &p) {
    std::uint32_t length;

    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&length);
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p.type));
    length = ntohl(length);
    p.type = ntohl(p.type);

    if (isIEND(length, type)) {
        is.setstate(std::ios::fail);
        return is;
    }        

    p.resize(length);
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(p.data.data());
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p.CRC));
    p.CRC = ntohl(p.CRC);

    if (computeCrc(p.data) != p.CRC) {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Putting all this together, we'd read a PNG file something like this:

```cpp
std::ifstream input("somefile.png");

if (!input >> pngHeader) {
    std::cerr << "not a png file\n";
}
std::vector<PngChunk> chunks(std::istream_iterator<PngChunk>(input), {});
```

At this point, we've read in all the png chunks, verified all their CRCs, etc., so they're ready to process (decompress, display, etc.)

#### Summary

- Don't store data for which you have no use.
- Reading from a file is a case where `reinterpret_cast` often makes sense.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. I'm learning the language by learning an image codec, and that's why I'm interested in storing bytes to write later (maybe the wrong approach); your interpretation of my question was spot on, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Make the vector the type you need and cast the ifstream input at the earliest opportunity.

Moreover I'd suggest that if this is binary data rather than text, you use `std::uint8_t`.

```cpp
std::vector<std::uint8_t> chunk_reader( std::vector<std::uint8_t>& b,
                                        std::ifstream &f) 
{
    char c { };

    for(int i { }; i < b.size(); ++i) 
    {
        f.get(c);
        b[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(c) ;
    }

    return b;
};
```